# How to disable certain minutes in Bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker

I am creating a webpage for my assignment and the operating hours is from 2.00pm until 10.30pm. I managed to use enabledHours to enable the hours to be selected, but I don't know how to disable the times from 10.31pm onwards (10.31pm - 10.59pm). May I know what is the way to achieve this?

```js
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      defaultDate: moment(),      
      maxDate: moment(),          
      ignoreReadonly: true,       
      enabledHours: [14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm A'
  })
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    Date and Time Visited <span style="color: red;"> * </span>
      <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ..

```
disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })], [moment({ h: 18 }), moment({ h: 24 })]]
```

I Hope Its HelpFull for Your Problem ...
More Details Approch This Website [Refernece Website](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/)

Comment: But moment is only for today, right? I want the hours to be disabled all the days

Comment: Actually I have enabled the hours from 2pm - 10pm, but now I want to disable the hours from 10.31pm onwards